# How to use Netlify DNS for domains managed by AWS Route 53?

Tags: amazon-route53, netlify

I have a domain registered at Route 53, but I want to have Netlify manage the DNS for this domain (the entire domain, unlike other questions about subdomains). I set the NS record for the domain to point to Netlify's name servers, but Netlify's custom domain configuration tool still claims that DNS is not configured correctly.

Below is a screenshot showing my current Route53 hosted zone configuration, with the NS records clearly pointed at Netlify's DNS servers.  I waited for DNS propagation timeouts, [flushed](https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/cache) Google's DNS cache, and tried other suggestions and nothing worked.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem turned out to be that setting the NS records in the hosted zone doesn't actually let Netlify manage the DNS for the domain. Instead, you need to change the nameservers in the Registered Domains section of the Route 53 console. (NOT the Hosted Zones section.)

[image]

On that page, remove the AWS nameservers and add Netlify's nameservers. It will look like this when it's done:  (Note that your nameserver hostnames may be different; copy them from Netlify's Custom Domain page)

[image]

Kudos to Netlify's support team for writing a [doc](https://answers.netlify.com/t/support-guide-i-changed-my-name-servers-dns-on-aws-route53-but-i-m-still-having-issues/722) that explains how to do this. It was admittedly hard to find this doc in Google because there are so many different Netlify docs about various DNS intricacies. But eventually Googling helped me find it.

In retrospect, it's now obvious to me that adding DNS records to a zone (even NS records!) can't change the nameservers used by the domain. But it would have been nice if the AWS console included this info when I edited the NS records so I didn't waste a few hours.

Leaving this answer here for the next victim.

Comment: THANK YOU for taking the time to write this up. It is indeed hard to find the correct documentation on this, and I was making the same exact mistake you made at first.

Answer (score 0):

For domain registered at Route 53 and Netlify managing the DNS. It worked for me by changing the name servers both from the "Registered Domain" area and "Hosted Zone".

Comment: Once you change the Registered Domain, the changes you made in Hosted Zone are ignored because the non-AWS DNS provider's servers will be the only servers answering queries for that domain. So you can change or not change the Hosted Zone settings and it won't make a difference either way.